# Проблемы со стиранием строки из файла C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема с стиранием строки из файла. Пишу бота для соц. сети который выдает аккаунты от Uplay и тут такая проблема при выдачи аккаунта он должен его стереть из текстовика (стереть именно тот аккаунт который выдал) и я это сделал так

```
FileStream file1 = new FileStream("accounts.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file1);
for (int i = 1; i < acc.Count; i++)
{
    writer.WriteLine(acc[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(acc[i]);
}
writer.Close();
```

Но записывает он не так как хотелось бы.

acc это лист содежащий в себе такие элементы

```
example1@example.ex:password1:Origin
example2@example.ex:password2:Origin
example3@example.ex:password3:Origin
example4@example.ex:password4:Origin
example5@example.ex:password5:Origin
```

После записи в файле должно быть так

```
example2@example.ex:password2:Origin
example3@example.ex:password3:Origin
example4@example.ex:password4:Origin
example5@example.ex:password5:Origin
```

Comment: А что в реальности оказывается в файле?

Comment: Ну и вы не закрываете `file1`, может быть, проблема в этом.

Comment: `FileStream` и `StreamWriter ` реализуют интерфейс `IDisposable`, поэтому рекомендую подобные вещи оборачивать в `using`, а на щет удаления совсем не ясно, в примере запись в файл....

Comment: @VladD, `StreamWriter` - это адаптер/декоратор и при его закрытии закроется и то что за ним, так ведь? Ну хотя, я бы предпочел все равно его явно закрывать.

Comment: Ну и можно вышеприведенный код упростить до такого: `File.WriteAllLines("accounts.txt", acc.Skip(1));`

Comment: @Андрей: Хм, и правда. Я привык всё, что `IDisposable`, оборачивать в `using`.